# fireEvent not properly calling event in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm currently testing an input using [Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest) & [react-testing-library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library). I'm trying to test whether the onChange function fires whenever my input's field changes. Here's an example of my code:

```
const placeHolder = 'first name';
const onChange = jest.fn();

test('<InputText/>', () => {

  const {getByPlaceholderText} = render(
    <InputText placeholder={placeHolder} onChange={onChange} />
  );

  const input = getByPlaceholderText(placeHolder);

  fireEvent.change(input, {
    target: {value: 'pls work'},
  });

  expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Here's what a get in the terminal when I run this test:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.
```

I've used the fireEvent.click() function in other tests without any issues yet, but fireEvent.change() doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: This has been [noted as an issue in Github](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/issues/175) [CLOSED].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that my `<InputText/>` component takes in a `onChangeFunc` prop, while I was trying to give it a regular `onChange` prop. Once I realized that and gave it the correct prop, it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling this

```
expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

you can try

```
expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
```